# Storing a list of data from multiple files in array

Tags: python, file-io, tkinter

Alright what i am doing is taking the contents of ONE .log file ONLY, storing it in an array, then outputting it in a multiple listbox as follows:

```
filelog_ext=".log" #log extension

#open one log file
f = open("%s\%s%s" % (path,filename,filelog_ext),"r")
#init aray      
array = []
#copy contents of file to array
for line in f:
    array.append( line )
f.close()
#insert each array content to multilistbox
self.mlb.insert (END, ('%s' % (array[0]),'%s' % (array[1]),'%s' % (array[2]),'%s' % array[3])))
    self.mlb.pack (expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
```

what i want to do now is taking contents of MANY .log files, outputting them in arrays and then outputting them in a multiple listbox.

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
for files in os.listdir("."):        
        if files.endswith(".log"):  #this will take all my files ending with .log

    #not sure how to go about and take all files ending with .log, copying them to array and saving them to the multilistbox mlb
```

Can anyone please help me ?

UPDATE:
@john zwink
i have tried to integrate your code don't know if im doing it the right way but it still doesnt work. Error is "Index list out of range"

```
    path = "C:\sdmdownloads"        
    array = []
    for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, filelog_ext)):
       with open(filename) as f:
           array.extend(f)
           self.mlb.insert (END, ('%s' % (array[0]),'%s' % (array[1]),'%s' % (array[2]),'%s' % (array[3])))
           self.mlb.pack (expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
```

Comment: your file doesn't have 4 lines?

Comment: I can't tell: are you expecting to get the first token of the first line as array[0], or the first line of each file as array[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import glob
import os

filelog_ext=".log" #log extension
array = []

for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, filelog_ext)):
    with open(filename) as f:
        array.extend(f)
```

Comment: what does array.extend(f) actually do?
I have updated the code @John Zwink please tell me if it is good

Comment: Extend puts all the items from its argument at the end of the list.  So after the loop is done the array will have all the lines from all the files.

Comment: The array should be size 4 as there are 4 entries in each of my log files.
also my multilistbox supports 4 items that are inserted in 4 colums

is it possible to iterate the following

(1) open one .log file
(2) copy the 4 lines in log file to an array
(3) append my multilistbox with the 4 array lines
(4) loop this process again

Comment: Sure, but I'm not going to keep writing your Python for you. :)  I think you have the pieces you need now.